# Inconsistent figure note line spacing rendering pdf in Bookdown

Tags: r, pdf, bookdown, cross-reference, line-spacing

**I am trying to insert a figure note to render in pdf from the following code chunk:**

```
``{r boxfreshAe, out.width = c("49%","49%","49%","49%"),fig.align = "center", warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, error=FALSE, fig.pos="H",fig.show = 'hold', fig.cap='(ref:boxfreshAe)', echo=FALSE}
```

**the text note reads like this:**

(ref:boxfreshAe) Forest  of Ae - boxplot of fresh example (%) by management example. A): 0 - 15 cm depth; B): 15 - 30 cm depth; C): litter example; D): H horizon. Displayed are minimum, twenty-fifth percentile, fiftyeth percentile, seventy-fifth percentile and maximum. Black dots are observations that may be outliers accoring to the rule ± 1.5 * interquartile range, this being determined as as the upper quartile minus the lower quartile [@reference2015]. Same colour / shape dots are same block replication.

**but also this would work the same:**

(ref:boxfreshAe) example example example example example example example example example example example example example example example exampleexample example example example example example example exampleexample example example exampleexample example example example

**the above chunk contains box-and-whiskers plots and results in a pdf with a figure note that looks like this:**

---

[image]

---

This is not what I want because the figure is using the layout of the main text of my book which I setup in the index.Rmd with `linestretch: 2`.

Instead, when I insert a photo the figure note has a reduced line spacing. I would like this spacing (below) to be also in the figure above.

(ref:shallow-Hhor) detail of the H horizon in the Control treatment. This was consistently < 5 cm deep.

````
```{r shallow-Hhor, out.width = "50%" , fig.align="center",fig.pos="h", fig.cap='(ref:shallow-Hhor)', echo=FALSE}
````

---

[image]

---

Any help is very welcome, many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the chunk option from `fig.pos="H"` to `fig.pos="!h"`